# I have received Compile error using Cmake; Compiler used-clang; error : use of undeclared identifier 'sscanf_l'

Tags: compiler-errors

[The error log can be found here, looks like issue with #include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7ni4.png)

Comment: can you please edit your question with some information to solve the issue

Comment: @NIMISHAN added the error log